# How to prevent the finding "Validation.EncodingRequired" in Java

Tags: java, security

Recently, I used the AppScan Source to scan the coding, and it found out one of the finding which I don't know how to fix and pass to the scanner or is it a false alarm?

Here's my code.

```
  public static void copyFileUsingFileStreams(File source, File dest)
    throws IOException
  {
    InputStream input = null;
    OutputStream output = null;
    try
    {
      input = new FileInputStream(source);
      output = new FileOutputStream(dest);
      byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
      int bytesRead;
      while ((bytesRead = input.read(buf)) > 0) {
        output.write(buf, 0, bytesRead); //Scanner reported that's a vulnerability in API OutputStream.write()
      }
    }
    finally
    {
      input.close();
      output.close();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks fine to me. There's no need for an encoding if you're writing bytes. If you were writing characters, that would be a different matter.

That said, you really ought to be wrapping your streams in buffered versions:

```
output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dest));
```

and similarly for `input`. That doesn't affect anything to do with encodings, but it will make the file I/O more efficient.

You should also change your `finally` block:

```
finally
{
    if (input!=null)
        input.close();
    if (output!=null)
        output.close();
}
```

When you start to catch and deal with `IOException`s, as you ought to be doing, you'll be risking a `NullPointerException` if anything goes wrong while your streams are being created.

Comment: Thanks chiastic for explain this matter :-)